# How long do the extended access_token lives?

Tags: facebook, token

Just read about the offline_access permission being removed and therefore having the new system of "[extended access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token)".

My problem is that i'd like to save the expiration timestamp to take care that the saved access tokens are always valid, but the Documentation doesn't provide a time that the extended token is valid for.

Does anyone have more information regarding that?
It'd be interesting to know if they long-living tokens are valid for days, weeks or months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the new endpoint which is explained in the post you linked to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The response will have this form:

> access_token=xxxxx&**expires**=yyyyy

The expires param is what you are after I believe.
Long lived tokens are good for 60 days, and you can check tokens (for debugging) with the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) which will tell you everything you need to know about the token.

---

## Edit

A few more things.
The "expires" parameter gives you the time left until expiration, so the expiration time is `timestamp of now + expires`.

It's easy to check this with out the need to do any development, just create a fb app (if you don't have one), go to the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) and copy the user token from your app, then using curl make a request to the new endpoint.

As for extending the long lived tokens, there's no way to do that, you'll need to re-authenticate the user after that, as it states in the same post:

> If you pass an access_token that had a long-lived expiration time, the
>   endpoint will simply pass that same access_token back to you without
>   altering or extending the expiration time

Another point is that you can get long lived access tokens by using the [Server-Side authentication flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), but those too can not be extended.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, i had guessed the response was only the token.
Is there any way to extend that token for a longer duration?

Comment: Edited my answer. If this answers your question, please be sure to accept it.

Comment: Well, i already knew the informations you added (except that the tokens can't be extended anymore), but thanks for taking the time and answering my question.
Of course i accept the answer, i was just waiting on a response to my commented additional question.

Answer (score -1):

It only returns back access_token not

access_token=xxxxx&expires=yyyyy as mentioned above.

Atleast that is what I can see...